# Intellij not including every file in build

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, javafx, tornadofx

I converting my **JavaFX/TornadoFX** project into a gradle project, I have all my resources in a **package** called resources... everything is working but when I build the project the packages, that don't contain any source code, don't move to the jar/build folder.

Since I am loading my fxml, css and font files from the package, I would need to tell intellij somehow to include this package...

Any ideas?

I tried creating marking the package as a resources but without any success

I also tried creating a tornadoFX project and then copying the files with the resource package... also did not work.

I tried creating a random class inside the resource package and only the class was copied to the jar/build folder

Is there a way how to tell intellij to include **everything** in the module not just the source code?

EDIT: For better understanding of my problem I added some screenshots

this is how my src dir looks like:

[image: Src file]

but when I build it (it does not contain the resource package...):

[image: Out file]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention is that by default, only compiled classes in the source folders are copied to the build folder. You should place arbitrary files you want to include in your build into `src/main/resources`.

To access files put into `src/main/resources` from the classpath of your application, you should refer to them by the full path. So `src/main/resources/myfile.txt` would be accessible via `/myfile.txt`.

You can create folders under the resources folder, so that `src/main/resources/views/MyView.fxml` would be accessible via `/view/MyView.fxml`.

If you mirror the package structure of your source files, you can access a resource for a given View or Fragment using relative path only. So for the file `com.example.myapp.MyView`, you could create `src/main/resources/com/example/myapp/MyView.fxml`. It would be picked up automatically for the `fxml` delegate, or via `resources["MyView.fxml"]` from within `MyView`.